# Does "Cheat!" effectively give you two more hands?

Tags: munchkin

Suppose you have a player who has a two-handed weapon A and another two-handed weapon B. He can use either of them without any problems, but not both as he only has two hands.

With the card "Cheat!" he can use both of them. But now he gets a third card C, also two-handed, which he likes to use against a monster. So for one round he puts A and B in his back-pack (it's still in front of the player, but he does not use A or B, but C). Can the player in one of the following rounds use A and B (together, without C) again?

I thought Cheat! would disable the "checking-mechanism" once, when the card comes into game. After that, when anything else changes something with the card it would have to be discarded again. However, I'm not sure if that makes sense. For example, if you used Cheat! because the weapon is only usable by a thief and you are a blogger, it would seem strange to me if you lose the weapon because you changed to a kid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you play the Cheat card it is attached to a specific item, either A or B in this case (let's assume A). With the additional item C you can use either A & B together or A & C together, but not B & C together.

The Cheat card only is discarded if you lose the item (for example from getting killed) It doesn't get discarded just because you un-equip the card temporarily.

Comment: What if you "cheated" a two-handed weapon you could have actually used before? Can you still, later in the game, use it together with another 2-handed weapon?

Comment: Yes, Cheat! allows you to cheat on hands in addition to things like Race/Class/etc. Basically with Cheat! you check if everything else is legal then add the cheated item regardless of if it is legal or not.

Comment: @moose If you have a cheated 2H weapon and you want to equip something else, first unequip the cheated weapon, then equip the other weapon, then re-equip the cheated weapon. You can only cheat the cheated weapon, and so you have to equip it last. If you did it the other way around (equip the cheated weapon and then the regular weapon), I think you would actually be cheating. I don't see anything in the FAQ or the rules that says you grow two more hands.